# Read ini file in PHP, not parse

Tags: php

When using parse_ini_file, it will attempt to read and understand the ini file. I'm looking for a solution that will read the file, place it into arrays much like parse_ini_file does, however I don't want it to get to the special characters in my ini file and spit an error that it can't parse them. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

ini file for reference:

```
[IMPORT]
email=email@thisisanemail.com
location=
Description=Order Form
name=*.xls*
matrixfile=
matrix_field=
matrix_disc_type_column=
matrix_disc_percentage_column=
fixed=XLS
separator=|
RowTerminator=
headerrows=13
footerrows=0
maxexcelcolumns=7
```

If I parse this, it gets stuck on the seperator "|" but I need that there.

Comment: `file_get_contents` will get the contents of a file.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php or `fread`...http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: can you quote the separator?  `separator="|"`

Comment: Thanks. How would I turn this into an array with that? Explode? How would I specify a delimiter for that?

Comment: I have about a hundred of these ini files, and I'm not too sure if quoting the ini would affect my other piece of software sadly!

Comment: Oh if you want an array use `file`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: Oh interesting, I'll have an experiment with `file`, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `parse_ini_file` with the `scanner_mode` parameter to specify `INI_SCANNER_RAW`, then option values will *not* be parsed (see
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).